# Can enemy Pokémon run out of PP for their moves and use Struggle?

Tags: pokemon-series

Say that I am battling a Pokémon, either a wild one or one owned by a trainer. If it uses the same move enough times (perhaps a Magikarp who keeps using Splash), is it possible for it to run out of PP and use [Struggle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Struggle_(move))?

I'm especially interested in third, fifth, and sixth generation because that's the ones I own, but information for all generations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, also your opponents do have PP. This means they will use Struggle if they run out their PP. Several people on [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/946308-pokemon-platinum-version/48723829) have seen a Legendary Pokemon hitting himself with Struggle after a long battle.

This is true for each generation, except for [Gen I](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Power_Point):

> In Generation I, all AI opponents had unlimited PP.

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/271718/87579)'s another related answer, for reference.